# Visualizing filter weights in tf.layers.conv2d

Tags: tensorflow

I am using `tf.layers.conv2d` in TensorFlow V1.0 to do convolution.

An example is as follows :

```
conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(batch_images, filters=96,
                                     kernel_size=7,
                                     strides=2,
                                     activation=tf.nn.relu,
                                     kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer_conv2d(uniform=False),
                                     bias_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(uniform=False),
                                     kernel_regularizer=tf.nn.l2_loss,
                                     bias_regularizer=tf.nn.l2_loss,
                                     name='conv1')
```

I then try to collect the filter weights as follows :-

```
l1weights = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.WEIGHTS, 'conv1')
```

However although the network is getting trained, I get `[]` on evaluating `l1weights` inside a session.

How do I extract the filter weights and visualize them using `tf.summary.image` ?

Comment: Try changing tf.GraphKeys.WEIGHTS  to GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES

Comment: I tried it did not work and gave the same output `[]`

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I'm having the exact one.

Answer (score 10):

I managed to get the weights using the following

```
conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(
    inputs=input_layer,
    filters=32,
    kernel_size=[5, 5],
    padding="same",
    activation=tf.nn.relu, name='conv1')

kernel = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.VARIABLES, 'conv1/kernel')[0]
bias = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.VARIABLES, 'conv1/bias')[0]
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This looks good, but I'm getting the error `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Tensor must be 4-D with last dim 1, 3, or 4, not [3,3,1,64]
  [[Node: conv1_2 = ImageSummary[T=DT_FLOAT, bad_color=Tensor<type: uint8 shape: [4] values: 255 0 0...>, max_images=3, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](conv1_2/tag, conv1/kernel/read)]]` using 64 `3x3` filters on a grayscale image. Ideas?

Comment: That is because the tf.summary.image expects a tensor of the form [images,height,width,channel]. You can transpose the dimensions with the following code: `kernel_transposed=tf.transpose(kernel,[3,0,1,2])` then using that in the summary. `tf.summary.image('kernel',kernel_transposed)`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the class-based layer API, in `tf.contrib.keras.layers.Conv2D` which exposes the variables as members of the layer object.

Also make sure you're fetching the variables in the same session in which you trained the model, or you will get uninitialized variable errors.